# Can't return the answer

Tags: java

The answer should be returned but it does not display for some reason. I have printed within for loop and seen that it's correct answer.

```
public class Salary
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        double [] salary = {20000.00};
        double riseRate = 1.07;

        calculateSalary(salary, riseRate);
    }
    public static double [] calculateSalary(double [] salary, double riseRate)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<salary.length; i++)
        {
            salary [i] = salary [i] * riseRate;
        }
        return salary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an array. The salary is in the the first position of you array. If you want to see the salary you would need to use

```
return salary[0];
```

in your method.

or

```
System.out.println(calculateSalary(salary,riseRate)[0]);
```

in the main.

What you're trying to print right now is the actual array, not a value.

I am not sure why you are doing it like this, though.
Why not just use a double instead of double[]?

Comment: Ok, then what you have is fine. But somewhere in your program you would probably do double[] salaries = calculateSalary(salary,riseRate); Then loop through the salaries array to print them.

Answer (score 5):

That's because you're not printing out the answer.  Add a print statement in `main`.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(calculateSalary(salary, riseRate)[0]);
```